# Consumir Servicio web bajo Https en Java?

Tags: java, webservice

Intento Consumir Servicio web bajo `Https` en Java desde NetBeans y no llega la petición.
Ya lo agregue el certificado en el `keyStore` de Java y sigue sin funcionar.
Alguna Ayuda/Sugerencia ..!

Me dice el siguiente error en la consola de Java

> GRAVE: cannot get httpConnection outputstream
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target
>           at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
>           at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1747)
>           at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:241)
>           at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:235)
>           at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1209)
>           at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:135)
>           at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593)
>           at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529)
>           at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:943)
>           at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188)
>           at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1215)
>           at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1199)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:434)

Comment: Me parece que debes actualizar tu librería de seguridad de Java. Esto también se conoce como el [Java Cryptography Architecture (JCA)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html). Básicamente, consiste en ir al sitio oficial de Java y descargar el Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) apropiado para tu versión de Java (puedes encontrar desde Java 6), agregar esta librería en tu JDK (las instrucciones vienen con el jar que descargas) y probar nuevamente el consumo de tu servicio. Adicional, convendría instalar el certificado SSL en tu equipo.

Comment: El certificado ya lo instale en mi PC, intentare con lo primero que mencionas. Gracias.